# how to extract a string between two strings in R

Tags: r

I have a string column in a dataframe:

```r
a = c("yhj-22k_loki_res", "jh_22k_lok_res", "fgdjh_22k_lk_res", "jhkkl_kkff_22k_lo_res", "j_22k_mm_res", "ko-jh_22k_lm_res")
```

I want to extract whatever between `22k_` and `_res`, that is

```
"loki", "lok", "lk", "lo", "mm", "lm"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex lookaround to extract characters (`.*`) that succeed after the substring "22k_" and precedes "_res"

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(a, "(?<=22k_).*(?=_res)")
[1] "loki" "lok"  "lk"   "lo"   "mm"   "lm"
```

Answer (score 0):

or `str_match()`

```
str_match(a, "(?<=22k_).*(?=_res)")

    [,1]  
[1,] "loki"
[2,] "lok" 
[3,] "lk"  
[4,] "lo"  
[5,] "mm"  
[6,] "lm"
```

another option

```
regmatches(a,gregexpr("(?<=22k_).*(?=_res)",a,perl = TRUE))

[[1]]
[1] "loki"

[[2]]
[1] "lok"

[[3]]
[1] "lk"

[[4]]
[1] "lo"

[[5]]
[1] "mm"

[[6]]
[1] "lm"
```